# subscribe to HTTP-service to pass an object to a form in a child component with Angular 4 Router with Observable

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-services

I apologize if this question seems to be a double, but I have searched the resource up and down and upon reading many threads and the Angular.io tutorial, I still cannot figure out how exactly to achieve my goal, although I have a pretty good understanding of the possibilities now.

My parent component (which is nothing more but a header + ) an object with an HTTP-service, which I would like to subscribe to from a child-component, in order the form in the child component gets pre-filled with object data.

Here is my code:
(ProjectsService)

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {
  private projectsUrl = environment.apiurl + 'projects';
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private extractData(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.projectsUrl)
                    .map(response => response.json() as Project[])
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProject(id: String): Observable<Project> {
    const url = `${this.projectsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(response => response.json() as Project)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

parent (ProjectComponent)

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  project: Project;

  constructor(
    private projectsService: ProjectsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => {
        return this.projectsService.getProject(params.id);
      }).
      subscribe(project => this.project = project);
   }    
}
```

(routing module)

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { 
    path: 'project/:id', 
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'settings', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent
      },
```

child (SettingsComponent):

```
export class SettingsComponent {
  @Input() project: Project;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private projectsService: ProjectsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {  

    ***I think it's here that I need a subscription to the HTTP-service but I cannot figure out how to ****

    this.project = {
            (...some porject properties to fill the data in the form)
   }
  }

}
```

Many thanks in advance for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by subscribing to the HTTP-service from within the child component but using `this.route.parent.params` instead of `this.route.params`